# Get max time of grouped by time series dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Date                 User    Tag
2-22-2022 09:00:00   u1      a
2-22-2022 10:00:00   u1      b
2-22-2022 11:00:00   u2      c
2-23-2022 09:00:00   u1      a
2-23-2022 10:00:00   u2      b
```

Want to creat, for each user, a column with the time difference between followed users/records.

Something like:

```
df["diff"] = df.groupby("user")["StartT"].diff().shift(-1)


Date                 User    Tag   diff
2-22-2022 09:00:00   u1      a      1 hour
2-22-2022 10:00:00   u1      b      23 hours
2-22-2022 11:00:00   u2      c      23 hours
2-23-2022 09:00:00   u1      a      NaN 
2-23-2022 10:00:00   u2      b      NaN
```

What I want to do is get, for each user (daily), and for each tag, the tag the user spent more time in.

Output:

```
Date                 User    Tag
2-22-2022 10:00:00   u1      b
2-22-2022 11:00:00   u2      c
2-23-2022 09:00:00   u1      a
2-23-2022 10:00:00   u2      b
```

Tried to `groupby(user, date(1day), tag)['diff].sum()`.idxmax() ?

There might be multiple tags per day/user, that's why i'm grouping by tag

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I had to split your calculation of the "diff" column in two steps to reach the same output as you:

```
>>> df["diff"] = df.groupby("User")["Date"].diff()
>>> df["diff"] = df.groupby("User")["diff"].shift(-1)
```

We'll also fill the NaN values on the "diff" columns by calculating the hours remaining to end the day (useful at the end of your data).

```
>>> df["diff"] = df["diff"].fillna(df["Date"].dt.date + pd.DateOffset(days=1) - df["Date"])
>>> df
                 Date User Tag            diff
0 2022-02-22 09:00:00   u1   a 0 days 01:00:00
1 2022-02-22 10:00:00   u1   b 0 days 23:00:00
2 2022-02-22 11:00:00   u2   c 0 days 23:00:00
3 2022-02-23 09:00:00   u1   a 0 days 15:00:00
4 2022-02-23 10:00:00   u2   b 0 days 14:00:00
```

Now, we apply `.groupby` to group by "User", day (using `df["Date"].dt.date`), and "Tag" to calculate the total time spent on each "Tag":

```
>>> times = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
>>> df_total_diff = df.dropna().groupby(["User", times.dt.date, "Tag"])["diff"].sum().reset_index()
>>> df_total_diff
  User        Date Tag            diff
0   u1  2022-02-22   a 0 days 01:00:00
1   u1  2022-02-22   b 0 days 23:00:00
2   u1  2022-02-23   a 0 days 15:00:00
3   u2  2022-02-22   c 0 days 23:00:00
4   u2  2022-02-23   b 0 days 14:00:00
```

Finally, we can group by "User" and "Date" to find the most consumed "Tag":

```
>>> df_output = df.loc[df_total_diff.groupby(["User", "Date"])["diff"].idxmax()]
>>> df_output
             Date User Tag
1 2022-02-22 10:00:00   u1   b
2 2022-02-22 11:00:00   u2   c
3 2022-02-23 09:00:00   u1   a
4 2022-02-23 10:00:00   u2   b
```